# Does my javascript contain repetitive code that can be reduced?

Tags: javascript, non-repetitive

I feel like there is too much repetitive code going on here. All I am doing is doing a basic regex match for a string in the URL. If a match is found, I find an li with a class (.index, .grid, .type) and add the active class. This is just for my main nav in an attempt to make it some what dynamic. However, I feel like there is a more efficient way to code this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var myLocation = window.location;
var convertURL = new String(myLocation);
var index = /index/i;
var grid = /grid/i;
var type = /type/i;
var urlIndex = convertURL.match(index);
var urlGrid = convertURL.match(grid);
var urlType = convertURL.match(type);
if(urlIndex) {
$('.index').addClass('active'); 
}else if(urlGrid) {
$('.grid').addClass('active');
}else if(urlType) {
$('.type').addClass('active');
    }

});
```

Comment: This would be far more appropriate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ You might get closed down here as you're looking for an optimization as opposed to an issue with your code.

Comment: You don't need so many variables. Just set `var url = window.location.href` and put the rest into the conditions of the `if` statements.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing working code

Comment: I am new here so sorry if this code is not appropriate for this location. I will post it over where krillgar suggested.

Comment: I posted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51720/does-my-javascript-contain-repetitive-code-that-can-be-reduced

Comment: posted the answer there also

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    ["index", "grid", "type"].forEach(function(term){
        if(new RegExp(term, "i").test(location.href)) 
            $("." + term).addClass("active"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Can go even shorter if done like `(function(term){/*code here*/}(['index', 'grid','type']))` :)

Comment: Yeap, that's an option. ;)

Comment: Um, why that `setClass` function at all? Just do `["index", "grid", "type"].forEach(…)`

Comment: Uhh... =D, you're totally right... just removed it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // use single var per function, good for minimizing and other stuff
    var

    i,

    // new string literal, not String object
    convertURL = '' + window.location,

    // the array of strings keeps only the difference from the repetitive code
    classes = ['index', 'grid', 'type'],

    // using functions with proper arguments reduces repetitivness
    matches = function (regex) {
        return convertURL.match(new RegExp(regex, 'i'));
    }

    // var
    ;

    // always use += instead of ++ -> makes for clear intention
    for (i = 0; i < classes.length; i += 1) {
        if (matches(classes[i])) {
            // returning out of this function stops iteration
            return $('.' + classes[i]).addClass('active');
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: How is the intention of `++` (increment by 1) less clear than `+=` (add something)?

Comment: Using `i+=1` is _add 1 to i and only then store it in i_, using `++` has subtle difference which may make you spend time guessing if it was supposed to be pre or post increment and especially if you encounter `i++; i++;` and don't know if it is copy-paste error or `i+=2`. Check this few minutes of video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taaEzHI9xyY&t=50m42s especially starting from 53:20.

Comment: Oh, Crockford is always opinionated, and very controversial :-) Seriously, in the loop only its side effect and not its result value matters, so it absolutely makes no difference whether you use `i++`, `++` or `i+=1` - only that `for (var i=0; i<….length; i++)` is an idiom that every programmer immediately recognices.

Comment: I don't say don't use it, I don't say always is bad, but one thing I found Crockford right about is: if I use it once, I get caught myself using it more and more times and in indiscriminate places. But in reality it's mostly because I don't bother setting the option to off in JSHint :)